# Breaker for pool heater

Tags: circuit-breaker

[image][image]can I put a double 50 amp pole in a 100 amp box

Comment: Can you post photos that show the breakers in the box?

Comment: Duplicate of this : https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/163776/97780

Answer (score 1):

We can't speak you whether you CAN or not because we don't know anything about your capabilities. But will a 50A breaker plug into a 100A breaker panel? Of course. Do you have room for it physically? We don't know. Is the 100A panel already loaded so much that adding another 50A load will become a problem? We can't assess that from here.

Comment: It whant let down load Moore pics but I only have 7 20 amp breakers in the box

Comment: Doesn't mean much. You have to assess the LOAD that those 7 x 20A breakers represents, then there is what's called a "demand factor" that is intended to account for the fact that not all circuits will be loaded at 100% of their rating 100% of the time. It you want to do this yourself, you need to research and study up on how to determine this. We are not there, we cannot see it. If this confuses you, that's what Electricians do for a living.